# ajax get/post load php file with parameter

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, load

i have a hyperlink with data property id="Phone System"

```
<a id="Phone System" class="push" href="#">test</a>
```

i want to load a php file in div id="drop1" with get/post method

```
<div>
<div id="drop1"></div>
<div id="drop2"></div>

</div>
```

here is the ajax code, the data id="Phone System" will be send to php file dropcategory.php

```
$(function(){
   $('.push').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

       $.ajax({
          type : 'get',
           url : 'dropcategory.php', 
          data :  'cat='+id, 
       success : function(r)
           {

              $("#drop1").show();
           }
      });
   });
});
```

and here is the php file dropcategory.php

```
    require ('connect.php');
      $cat = $_GET['cat'];
   //some query operation
```

i have no idea how to show php file with determined parameter

Comment: Add the cat parameter to your url parameter `url : 'dropcategory.php?cat='+id`

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem but try, `data :  {cat:id}, ` instead of a string

Comment: i think the problem in the success function(r)?

Comment: I have no idea about what kind of job you intend to do here but I could see some problems from your code, you had invalid id(has space) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html?answertab=active#tab-top
wrong ajax data syntax

Comment: thank you all, it is work when i add $("#drop1").show().html(r); in success : function(r)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX POST example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the div with the response data:

```
$(function(){
   $('.push').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#drop1').load('dropcategory.php', {cat: $(this).attr('id')});
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you all, but it is work when i add $("#drop1").show().html(r); in success : function(r)

Comment: @ocit Also take a look at `ID Naming Rule` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
                  type : 'get',
                   url : 'dropcategory.php', 
                  data :  'cat='+id, 
               success : function(r)
                   {
                      $("#drop1").load("data.php?cat="+id);
                   }
              });
```

and :

```
require ('connect.php');
echo $cat = $_GET['cat'];
```